# IntelliJ idea - any way to change visual line wrapping icon?

Tags: intellij-idea

I really like Intellij's line wrapping feature with icons marking line wraps. Hovewer the default wrapping icon's readability is far from ideal.. is there any way I could fix this little problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current solution is to use standard unicode symbols from [supplementary arrows](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2900-297F) set: 2925 and 2926.

You can modify that by specifying other unicode (hex) codes via `idea.editor.wrap.soft.before.code` and `idea.editor.wrap.soft.after.code` properties in `idea.properties` file. Note that it's necessary to define both symbols, e.g. add to the `idea.properties` something like below:

```
idea.editor.wrap.soft.before.code=2906
idea.editor.wrap.soft.after.code=2907
```

Note that not all the fonts contain all the Unicode characters, so you have to choose the proper font in `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` and specify the symbol code that exists in the font that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what CrazyCoder said:

On a Mac, you'll need to go into finder and "show package contents" on the Intellij IDEA.app, then you can add lines to the idea.properties file in the "bin" folder. Here's the arrow codes I went with:

```
idea.editor.wrap.soft.before.code=219e
idea.editor.wrap.soft.after.code=21a0
```

Don't forget, you can also change their color in the program's preferences under "editor > colors and fonts > general > soft wrap sign".